# Zend Gdata Youtube API, upload video, change playlist

Tags: api, youtube, gdata, playlist

For an example I have such setup of video:

```
    $ytVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
    $ytVideoEntry->setVideoTags ('tag1, tag2, tag3');
    $ytVideoEntry->setVideoTitle ('some title');
    $ytVideoEntry->setVideoDescription ('video description');
    $ytVideoEntry->setVideoCategory ('category_name');
```

but I can't find how can I set playlist.

Does anybody know how to do it?